# Devices (FireTv/Chromebook) are not detecting under ubuntu when its connected via USB cable

Tags: usb, adb, iot, chromebook, amazon-fire-tv

Ubuntu is connected to FireTv via USB cable. But its not recognised in Linux machine when i entered 'lsusb'. Any suggestion or steps should I follow to make the connection?

Note: Same issue observed for Chromebook as well.